# Error Referencing ng2-bootstrap.umd.min.js in asp.net core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, ng2-bootstrap, umd

I am trying to use ng2-bootstrap with angular2 and asp.net core.

I reference "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.24" in package.json

When I try reference the node_models/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.min.js I get the following error

Uncaught Error: Module must be loaded as AMD or CommonJS

How can I fix the problem?
Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 0):

In my case I fixed the error by sticking to version "1.0.24" . So I did remove the "^" from the version.    Version "1.0.24" also has different files and there you can find the "ng2-bootstrap.min.js" file which you can use instead of the "ng2-bootstrap.umd.min.js" file.

Best regards,
Manrique